# How do you Create a single-bundle App/Archive using static libraries like Core-Plot?

Tags: iphone, archive, core-plot

I struggled a bit before I found an answer and so I'm posting it here.

Problem: Building archive with Core-Plot resulted in an Organizer error that said something about building a single-bundle archive. Issue seemed to be problem with headers located in /usr of Install_Root.

See below for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other ways. This one worked for me. Create run script in Build Phase of target App.

[image: deleteTest - deleteTest.xcodeproj]

Then run Archive. Wha-la!

Comment: While this may work the real solution can be found here https://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/c4915cb2398d51de/992ff17c5222a919 it involves moving the copy header files from public and private into project inside the build phases.